# How to determine what triggered a blur

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have a button on an AngularJS page that has numerous directives, and when tabbing to the button after a second or so it blurs. I can stop the blur event itself by adding an ng-blur and issuing a preventDefault(), but I'd like to be able to filter out when to preventDefault based on the cause of the blur. Is there any way to find out what the original source of the blur was?

Within the blur event handler I did a JQuery for (':focus') and it's empty, so that doesn't help for identification purposes. I also didn't find anything useful in the $event object passed into the event handler.

Also, the problem is exclusive to MS Edge, sorry for omitting this originally.

Any ideas?

Thanks,

Matt

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Not really an answer other stating I couldn't find an actual way to programmatically determine the blur trigger, but I found the triggering event which was caused by someone using browser detection and assuming Chrome in the UA meant it was definitively Chrome.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

After the button loses focus, you can call:

```
document.activeElement
```

to see which element the browser has given focus.

As for what is causing the blur, you'll need to post your code so we can look at it or debug/properly step through your code.

Comment: document.activeElement comes up <body>. There's way too much code involved in this page to post it here and make a difference (at least 15 directives, 3 foundation layers, and a tinyMCE editor), I'm just hoping for some technique I'm not aware of.

Comment: As stated above, you'll need to properly debug your code by stepping through it with break points. Check the write-up specifically for MS Edge: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/documentation/f12-devtools-guide/debugger/
It looks like there's even a way to make every `blur` event trigger a break, which may help in your case.

Comment: I had issues getting Edge to debug the javascript built from the typescript.

Answer (score 1):

Check [event.relatedTarget](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FocusEvent/relatedTarget)

It is experimental feature, but widely supported.

Comment: It looks interesting, but is null in the event handler on Edge.